Determining rational solutions to $y^2 = 2(x^4 - 2x^3 - 2x - 1)$
I am trying to find all rational solutions to $y^2 = 2(x^4 - 2x^3 - 2x - 1)$
So far, I have tried to show that rational solutions to the above form an isomorphism with rational solutions to an elliptic curve, but to no avail.

We do have a factorization $x^4-2x^3-2x-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-2x-1)$. Might that be  relevant?

It could, but one method I am currently trying is by use of graphing it. It seems as if the graph is composed of two separate elliptic curves.

A real picture of an elliptic curve often has multiple connected components; is that what you mean?

I believe so, as in it has connected components

Hint: if $x$ is a rational number with $2$-adic order $m$, what is the $2$-adic order of the right side?

Could you go into more detail about the 2-adic order $m$. I don't exactly know where this would lead to.

The point is that the 2-adic valuation of $y$ should be even....... (Aside, the curve - a smooth proj closure of - has no points so can't be isomorphic to an elliptic curve)

I understand. Is there still a way to find all rational points on this curve?

@RavikanthAthipatla it has none, per the above hinted argument with $2$-adic valuations

Let $x=\frac{{2^m}q}{p}$ ($m\in \mathbb{Z}$, $p,q$ is odd) then $y^2=\frac{2({2^{2m}}q^2+p^2)({2^{2m}}q^2-{2^{m+1}}pq-p^2)}{p^4}$. It is easily shown that $2$-adic order of RHS is odd, while $2$-adic order of LHS should be even. This is contradiction, so there is no rational solutions.
